# Android - Video downloaded from cloud storage to android photo gallery does not appear at top of photo gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the following code to download a video from a google cloud storage bucket in android. It works, but the video appears in the photo gallery at the timestamp that the video was uploaded to google cloud storage on android. I want the video to appear at the top of the photo gallery as the most recent video. Maybe there is some meta-data android is reading from the bucket?

I tried setting `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED`, `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN`, `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED` to the current time but that didn't work.

Anyone know what is going on?

```
var fos: OutputStream? = null
contentResolver?.also { resolver ->
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "file.mp4");
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    }
    val uri: Uri? =
        resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
    fos = uri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
}

val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
URL(weblink).openStream().use { input ->
    fos.use { fileOut ->
        while (true) {
            val length = input.read(buffer)
            if (length <= 0)
                break
            fileOut?.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }
        fileOut?.flush()
        fileOut?.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing could be related to the way Android's MediaStore library handles the metadata of the video file. The metadata may be inherited from the original file, which could be causing the file to appear at the timestamp when it was uploaded to Google Cloud Storage.

To work around this issue, you can try setting the metadata values after the video file has been downloaded. Here's how you can modify your existing code to achieve this:

```
var fos: OutputStream? = null
var uri: Uri? = null
contentResolver?.also { resolver ->
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "file.mp4")
    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
}
uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
fos = uri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
}

val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
URL(weblink).openStream().use { input ->
fos.use { fileOut ->
    while (true) {
        val length = input.read(buffer)
        if (length <= 0)
            break
        fileOut?.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }
    fileOut?.flush()
    fileOut?.close()
}
}

// Now that the video file has been downloaded, update its metadata
uri?.also { videoUri ->
val videoValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
}
contentResolver.update(videoUri, videoValues, null, null)
}
```

Comment: Did not work. Your response sounds like a bot.

Comment: :| ok then ask bots not here